# QGIS - Very slow map rendering and WMS timeout

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, wms

I am working on a powerful desktop, it was custom made so I do not know the exact specs however ram is 64gb and it was made for 3d modeling.

I am finding QGIS 3.22.2 to be very slow when rendering maps in print layout view, currently, I have a very simple map with one polygon and a wms map. Once in print layout, the rendering process can take over 10 minutes, I also receive multiple network requests to tile time out (often over 100).

What is causing this?

It is very frustrating.

I do find it is worse when I do not use WGS84 coordinate system. Sadly for my work I need to use an ED50 coordinate system and I find it to cause lots of issues.

Quite often when rendering is complete, only part of the WMS map is rendered.. with areas being blank. I then have to restart the process.

Comment: Please provide the link to the WMS in question.

Comment: almost certainly a network issue - see if adding a local proxy cache to the WMS helps

Comment: Is the same computer that's running QGIS also serving the WMS locally?

Comment: Is it your WMS, or is it provided by an external party?

Answer (score 2):

If you have complicated legends, especially ones that are filtered using the 'Only show items inside linked map', this can severely impact the rendering speed. When making changes to the map, it would help to temporarily turn off that option.